# A question on analytic geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry

A point $Q(x_2,y_2)$ is on the line segment passing through $R(-2,5)$ and $S(4,1)$. Find the coordinates of $Q$ if it is twice as far from $R$ as from $S$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Write $Q$ is a weighted mean of $R$ and $S$, with weights $\frac23$ and $\frac13$ respectively, and project this relation on the axes.